# replace patterns in a text file with an update file

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, pattern-matching

I have this 2 csv file

old.csv

```
station,32145,80
station,32145,60
```

new.csv

```
station,32145,80
station,32145,801
```

expecting result

result.csv

```
station,32145,80,no change
station,32145,801,new
station,32145,60,Delete
```

I have used `diff` and `awk` to do the job, but I have slight issue. The row has no changed or the one deleted updated correctly but the new one is not. Anyone can show me where is my mistake?

`diff -W999 --side-by-side old.csv new.csv | 
awk '/[|][\t]/{split($0,a,"[|][\t]");print a[2]" No Change"};/[\t] *<$/{split($0,a,"[|][\t]* *<$");print a[1]" Delete"};/>[\t]/{split($0,a,">[\t]");print a[2]" New"}'`

Comment: Is there a trailing comma in `new`?

Comment: yes, but I can remove that if that caused issue.

Comment: where does `sed` come into this problem? Please remove from description if you don't really need it. Good luck.

Comment: to do this in `sed` you do need two pipes `:/`

Comment: Does the order of the rows matter? I mean if both files are 10 lines long and line 2 in old.csv and line 7 in new.csv are both `station,32145,60` what would that mean for your output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
awk -F, '
NR==FNR && NF {a[$0","]++; next}
NF {print ($0 in a) ? $0"no change" : $0"new"; delete a[$0]}        
END {for (x in a) print x"delete"}' old.csv new.csv
```

#### Output:

```
station,32145,80,no change
station,32145,801,new
station,32145,60,delete
```

#### Update based on comments: Handle random `.` in second column

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
NR==FNR {gsub(/[.]/,"",$2);a[$0","]++; next}
NF {gsub(/[.]/,"",$2); print ($0 in a) ? $0"no change" : $0"new"; delete a[$0]}        
END {for (x in a) print x"delete"}' old.csv new.csv
```

Comment: `NF` is only needed if you have blank lines in csv (your initial question before the edit had them). If you don't have them, you can remove it. Either ways it won't hurt to have them.

Comment: thanks much, it's working as expected only I have issue the the 2nd column randomly has (.) in the middle. ex. (station,321.45.,80,) those row resulted as deleted.is (.) affect the result, can ignore the (.) any suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Code for [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

---

`new` without trailing commas:

```
awk -v OFS="," 'NR==FNR {a[$0]=$0;next};{b[$0]=$0};$0==a[$0] {print $0, "no change"};a[$0]==0 {print $0, "new"};END {for (x in a) {if (b[x]==0) {print a[x], "Delete"}}}' old new
```

`new` with trailing commas:

```
$awk  -v OFS="" 'NR==FNR {a[$0","]=$0",";next};{b[$0]=$0};$0==a[$0] {print $0, "no change"};a[$0]==0 {print $0, "new"};END {for (x in a) {if (b[x]==0) {print a[x], "Delete"}}}' old new
```